# SQL Server Job failing to delete html files out of a folder

Tags: sql-server, jobs

We have a simple job that runs every Sunday on sql server 2000. Copies files over, and then deletes any .txt, .rpt, .html and .log files.

It looks to me like it isn't finding any .txt and .rpt files and is reporting back no output generated, but those steps are passing.

Then for the del .html files, it reports back that it can't find any html files and fails.

The code is:

```
   COPY C:\DATA\LOGS\*.* C:\DATA\LOGS\Sunday\*.*    Succeeds 
   DEL  C:\DATA\LOGS\*.txt                          Succeeds
   DEL  C:\DATA\LOGS\*.rpt                          Succeeds 
   DEL  C:\DATA\LOGS\*.html                     FAILS 
   DEL  C:\DATA\LOGS\*.log                      Never gets here
```

Any ideas as to why it wouldn't like that del *.html ? Why wouldn't it just look for .html files, and when not finding any, just pass the step, and go onto the last step?

Comment: If you can post example code, that will help us considerably. I'm assuming you're using xpcmdshell or are you using a powershell script? Either way, I'd look towards cmd for better answers likely. The next idea is to have it print the list of files it sees to the window or another file and also introduce proper logging so you can get some more detailed answers as to what's occurring during this process.

Comment: Hi it is using "Operating System Command (CmdExec). I was able to get the code entered above. What is the 3 easy steps to have it print the list of files it sees. I could try that. Also what could I add for proper logging? I would like to try that as well... thanks

Comment: Can you post the code? I'm just going to be guessing at what's going on otherwise. For logging, there are two levels, the Cmd level and the stored procedure level. http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php That link shows basics on CMD for output, I always liked to have it log to a file with a timestamp stating the action and results of the action occurring, essentially having it loop and log the information to file from variables.

Comment: When you say post the code, that is what is in that box above. Each of those lines is one step. Like the first step is copy, 2nd one is del .txt etc

Comment: Are there any .HTML files in that directory?  Check and see if they are locked by another process.  If you want the job to continue even if errors are encountered then you need to break each command up into it's own step and configure the failure action for the step to just move on.

Comment: I just took over the database today, so will need to wait until sunday to get a look at what is in there, but I don't think there has been any txt, rpt, html for a while. I never thought of doing that. Each line is its own step, so I could say keep going if you get an error. Thanks for that point. That will help

Comment: Ah ok. Here's what I would try. 1. Inspect the file in properties, verify the extension is actually HTML under 'Type of File'. 2. Verify the HTML files are being copied in step 1, this confirms you can read them and see them. 3. Switch .log with .html, make that step come before the html file, does the HTML step fail, does the log step fail, do both fail or do either succeed? 4. Why not just use C:\DATA\LOGS\*.* for the delete CMD if you are moving it all anyway? 5. Side thought, maybe the html files are still being moved before the delete occurs?

Comment: Thanks Shaulinator. All good troubleshooting points that I will try, and didn't think of. I have to do this in the morning as it is our end of day here an hour ago, and not on the server now. One weird thing for me is it seems to be ok with looking for txt and rpt files. From what I could find today, there wasn't any in there last Sunday but still continued on. I don't know what that means when it says "No output generated". I think that must mean it didn't find any so moving on. If that was true, you would think it would do the same for html files.

Comment: That's correct, I would assume it would be the same or at least throw a different error. I'd still run through what I listed for troubleshooting, but I think detailed logging is a great proactive answer going forward so you have more verbose details to assist in the future. Did any of that work or does the issue persist?

Comment: I just got the change request to troubleshoot in today, so will look at it in the morning and will update here.

Comment: I am running tests, and this is what is happening which doesn't make sense. There are 4 files in there. Two with the extension .log.Dest and two with .log.Source...The first step says copy c:\folderA\*.*  c:\folderB\Sunday\*.*    . That works perfect. The next step says del c:\folderA\*.log and it fails because there aren't any .log files in there to delete. I'm not sure why it wouldn't just look, and say no .log files in there to delete and pass the step.

Comment: So basically this is a catch 22 situation. If the file isn't there, the job fails if you have it set to fail the job if the step fails. If you say skip the step, the delete could fail and the job would pass!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that, while there is always some file present (so the COPY always succeeds), there is not always a file with the specified extensions.

One quick-and-dirty solution - add the following lines between the COPY and the first DELETE:

```
ECHO z >> C:\DATA\LOGS\ZZZ_tmp.txt
ECHO z >> C:\DATA\LOGS\ZZZ_tmp.rpt
ECHO z >> C:\DATA\LOGS\ZZZ_tmp.html
ECHO z >> C:\DATA\LOGS\ZZZ_tmp.log
```

This will create one file with each required extension (or append a z to an existing file with the name).

If you want to go this way, make sure you:

- Pick a base file name that you will *never* see in reality, so you don't corrupt an existing file; and
- Document the purpose of the extra files.

Ideally, you'd want to create a solution where you don't fail the DELETE step if there's no matching files, instead of creating dummy files just to get deleted. This can probably be done with CMD.EXE; however, I'd suggest you implement a script in whatever language your department uses (or, at least in whatever language you're comfortable with). Unless you're comfortable with DOS (or whatever you call what CMD.EXE uses now), that's probably not your best solution.

Also - note the COPY will fail if there are no files in `C:\DATA\LOGS\` to begin with. This could also be handled by a script, as could what to do if both source and destination directory have a file with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just looking to see if I can write logic that basically says if exists, delete else quit

Answer (score 0):

I think this logic works

if exist C:\DATA\LOGS*.log DEL C:\DATA\LOGS*.log 
if not exist C:\DTSDATA\LOGS*.log exit(0)